# How I can get xml nodes which have child node value like node value in other document part

Tags: xml

I have xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
  <node1>
    <id>id1</id>
    <name>name1</name>
  </node1>
  <node1>
    <id>id2</id>
    <name>name2</name>
  </node1>

  <node2>
    <id>id1</id>
    <somevalue>0</somevalue>
  </node2>
  <node2>
    <id>id2</id>
    <somevalue>1</somevalue>
  </node2>
</parent>
```

I would like to get nodes node1 which has childe id equals to id in node2 with somevalue = 0

I can get id from node2 with 0 in somevalue:

```
node2[somevalue = 0]/id
```

But I can't create result xpath

I tried like this (it's not working):

```
node1[../node2[somevalue = 0]/id = id]/name
```

I can't create something else. Can you help me?

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean it's not selecting anything or just not selecting what you want? That xpath seems to work for me (selects the `name` element in the `node`). I did add `//` to it so context wouldn't matter.

Comment: "not working" is about php return error with message: 
SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid predicate in file.php on line 126.

But your comment help for me! Thank you. I found error in xpath text (I forget last ] in condition), correct it and all is working. Thank you.